# VLOOKUP error with output of formula using Right(),Len() and Find()

Tags: excel, find, excel-formula, vlookup

In table A I have a list of codes that contain a numerical component after 1-3 letters. I need to use the numerical value to find the corresponding year via the ranges detailed in table B.

```
Table A:            Table B:        

Code    Year        Value Min   Value Max   Year
AC19    ?           0           10          2011
ABC2    ?           11          20          2012
AC12    ?           21          30          2013
AFC30   ?           31          40          2014
GXC0    ?           41          50          2015
```

To separate out the number I have been using:

```
=(RIGHT(B7,LEN(B7)-(FIND("C",B7)+0)))
```

(Where B7 in this case is the first code in the table)

This works well as all codes have a C before the numerical component.

I found that using example numerical segments (without using the above formula) I could use VLOOKUP with the "True" flag. However when I attempted to run it using the numerical value generated with the above formula I got a #Ref! error.

Why would VLOOKUP suddenly stop working when using data collected from the formula above?

The ideal output would be:

```
Code    Year
AC19    2012
ABC2    2011
AC12    2012
ACF30   2012
GXC0    2011
```

Comment: Your formula to exctract numbers is almost right, the `+0` is misplaced. It should be: `=RIGHT(B7,LEN(B7)-FIND("C",B7))+0`

Comment: If you get #REF! error, though, that indicates a different error, possibly column index > number of columns in table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `AC19` is in B7, please try in C7 and copied down to suit:

```
=VLOOKUP(VALUE(RIGHT(B7,LEN(B7)-FIND("C",B7))),TableB,3)
```

Comment: Works perfectly! No idea why mine was not working! Thank you so much!

Comment: This wouldn't work for **ACF30**, or is that a typo?

Comment: Actually I see its AFC30 in the first table so I assume output table is a typo

Comment: It is a typo - I will fix it now! Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 3):

Functions like `LEFT`, `RIGHT` and `MID` always return text results so you get a data mismatch between the text formatted lookup value and your numeric table - the `VALUE` function employed by punts converts the lookup value to a number

Another possible approach:

`=LOOKUP(LOOKUP(100,RIGHT(B7,{1,2})+0),Table)`

**Explanation:**

This part of the formula retrieves the number from the end of the string (assuming at most 2 digits):

`LOOKUP(100,RIGHT(B7,{1,2})+0)`

The `RIGHT` function is returning an array which consists of the last 1 and last 2 characters of `B7`, so when `B7` = **AC19** that returns an array like this

{"9","19"}

The quotes indicate that these are text values but we want numbers, so the +0 converts this to the following

{9,19}

Now when we lookup a large value (relatively in this case) of 100 in that array we get a match with the **last** number, in this case **19**

[Note when there is only a single digit like in **ABC2** the array is `{"2","C"}` which converts with +0 to `{2,"#VALUE!"}` - `LOOKUP` ignores the error and still returns the last number, i.e. `2`]

so now `19` is the lookup value in our second `LOOKUP` function, assuming that **Table** is the the three columns of Table B (without headers).

This is a more "normal" `LOOKUP` function - `19` is looked up in the first column of Table and matches with the largest value smaller than or equal to `19`, i.e. **11**,. and then returns the value from the same row but in the **last** column of Table, i.e. `2012`

`LOOKUP` with a table array always matches in the first column of that table and returns a value from the last column (unless the table is wider than it is tall, in which case it matches with the first **row** and returns a value from the last **row**)

See attached example below:

The named range Table is shown in orange and the results in blue

[image]

Comment: @pnuts: i tried this myself, i couldn't get the exact results. I get very inconsistent results. Could somebody explain this formula step by step for me?

Comment: @barryhoudini: i still encounter a problem. here is the screenshot of my setup. It would be nice if you could share an example sheet, so I can download and see what is wrong in mine. Maybe the local settings.http://i.imgur.com/Fm4aUA5.png

Comment: @barryhoudini: and my table1 is F2:H6, without the headers.

Comment: @pnuts: yes, it was the trailing spaces. I had copied the example from the question without cleaning up the spaces. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the additional discussion around why I was getting these errors - another fantastic answer!